# What is the meta key of Recent products in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product, database-metadata

I have a small e-commerce site which is made by woocommerce. I want to display recent product in my home page and I could not able to do it so I have need Woocommerce recent post Meta key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `meta_key` for recent products, because it's based on date (i don't know which one exactly, you will have to look in your DB at `wp_posts` table).

But you can use **recent products** [woocommerce shortcode](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-5) on your homepage:

```
[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]
```

Or you can use [Feature products shortcode](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6):

```
[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]
```

Works the same as recent products but displays products that have been set as “featured.” If you use feature products, you could find this in DB.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show recent products on the home page you can use WooCommerce shortcode

**per_page:** how many products you want to show then page

**column :** columns attribute controls how many columns wide the products should be before wrapping.

```
 [recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists recent products – useful on the homepage. The ‘`per_page`’ shortcode determines how many products to show on the page and the `columns` attribute controls how many columns wide the products should be before wrapping.

```
array(
    'per_page' => '12',
    'columns' => '4',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
)

[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]
```